# How to improve SQL Teradata with OVER PARTITION BY

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query with more than 7 columns with some counts() and sum() values, I was very slow, then I was trying using OVER PARTITION BY , but in the result table I have a error "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group".

This is the query :

```
insert into  SQUEMA.TABLE_B
select 
SUBSTR(cast(date as char(6)) ,1,4) ||'-'|| SUBSTR(cast(date as char(6)) ,5,6) as date ,
column1,
column2,
column3,
.
.
.
.
column7,
count(column8) OVER (PARTITION BY date, column1,...,column7) as column8
SUM(column9) OVER(ORDER BY date ) as column9
from  SQUEMA.TABLE_A tb 
where tb.date between '201711' and '201812'
group by date, column1,...,column7;
```

Error

> Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Comment: Is `date` an integer yyyymm and you want to format it as `yyyy-dd`? `Trim(date  (FORMAT '9999-99'))`

Comment: Thanks you, works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
sum(count(column8)) OVER (PARTITION BY date, column1,...,column7) as column8
sum(sum(column9))) OVER (ORDER BY date ) as column9
```

This is how you use window functions with aggregation.

Comment: Thanks it was helpful.